# What is 'module' in the Apache2 source code?

Tags: c, apache

Take this line for example from [mod_lbmethod_bybusyness.c](https://github.com/apache/httpd/blob/fb87921a287a9fc604daa7d4a8add98abe03a471/modules/proxy/balancers/mod_lbmethod_bybusyness.c#L23):

`module AP_MODULE_DECLARE_DATA lbmethod_bybusyness_module;`

I don't know of a `module` keyword in C, what is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `module` keyword in C. It seems to be a `typedef` made in the projet (see [http_config.h](https://github.com/apache/httpd/blob/fb87921a287a9fc604daa7d4a8add98abe03a471/include/http_config.h#L341)).